# mySQL how do you do a chain of join?

Tags: mysql, sql, database, join

[image]

Hi! I am trying to figure out how to do a join in multiple steps in the same line of code. This is what i got so far, but I get an error 1064.

```
select * from jbcity
join jbsupplier on jbsupplier.city = jbcity.name where jbcity.state = "Mass"
join jbsupply on jbsupply.supplier = jbsupplier.id
join jbparts  on jbparts.id = jbsupply.part;
```

Comment: select c1, c2 ... from t1 join t2 on t1.c1 = t2.c1 join t3... where... I.e simply move the WHERE to the end.

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
select * from jbcity
join jbsupplier on jbsupplier.city = jbcity.name 
join jbsupply on jbsupply.supplier = jbsupplier.id
join jbparts  on jbparts.id = jbsupply.part where jbcity.state = 'Mass';
```